# TFS 2010 assembly file update with last successful build number

Tags: .net, tfs

In a .NET solution with multiple projects integrated in TFS 2010, I need a build which will update the output Assembly file version only if this is checked in otherwise its file version will be updated with its last successful build number. That means I need a mechanism by which i Can tell these are the assemblies which are changed from the last build.

I have a .net solution with multiple project files integrated with TFS 2010. Now I want my project releases to update its assembly version only if it is checked in since the last build. If the project is checked in since its last build the assembly version should be updated with the latest build number otherwise the assembly file version should be updated with the projects last successful build number.

Jim Lambs and Hofman's solution to update assembly version is been a great help although it does not guide this situation.

That means

Project A changed : Released File version 1.3.0.0 , File Assembly version 1.3.0.0 (Build 1.3.0.0)

Project B not changed : Released File version 1.1.0.0 File Assembly version 1.3.0.0 (Build 1.3.0.0)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what the "this" is you are referring to; however, here is an article that goes over how to set Assembly Version:

[Customize Team Build 2010 – Part 5: Increase AssemblyVersion](http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2010/05/13/Customize-Team-Build-2010-e28093-Part-5-Increase-AssemblyVersion.aspx)

From this example, you can create something to fit your specific needs I am sure.

Comment: Hi NgM, I need to find out if source code changed since its last successful build or not.